# JavaScript - Maths with arrays and more calcs

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm trying to do a project which consists on some buttons and when you click them a value is pushed into an array (custo). I need to add all the values of that array and store them in a variable, which I can't do properly… I tried joining with (" * "). after having that value in a variable I would need to multiply it by the value the user would give on the input……… furthermore, the final result would be displayed when the button  Calcular  is clicked, and when the reset button is clicked, the div with the result (resultado), would be cleaned and the array reset. Here is the code for what I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-cont">
        <div id="resultado"></div>
        <div class="bloco-estilo" id="penteado">
            <p>Penteado</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bloco-estilo" id="pintar">
            <p>Pintar</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bloco-estilo" id="pintar-opt">
            <ul class="cores">
                <li id="cor_verm">Vermelho</li>
                <li id="cor_loiro">Loiro</li>
                <li id="cor_cast" cast>Castanho</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="bloco-estilo" id="acabamento">
            <p>Acabamento</p>
        </div>






        <div class="lucro">
            <div class="lucro-dir">
                <p>Introduza o valor percentual de lucro</p>
                <input type="text" maxlength="2">
                <p>%</p>
            </div>

            <div class="lucro-esq">
                <button id="reset">Reset</button>
                <button id="calc">Calcular</button>
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>
    </div>






<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="function.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: row;
}

ul li {
display: inline;
padding: 0 40px;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: row;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}

.inner-cont {
width: 50%;
height: 80%;
background-color: #f2ce9e;
position: relative;
}

#resultado {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: snow;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px dashed #e39835;
}

.bloco-estilo {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
font-size: 20pt;
color: navy;
font-family: Arial;
margin-bottom: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 500ms ease;
}

ul li:hover {
background-color: #8b1555;
color: white;
}

.bloco-estilo:hover {
background-color: deeppink;
color: white;
}

.lucro {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
font-size: 12pt;
color: navy;
font-family: Arial;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}

.lucro-dir {
width: 50%;
height: 100px;
font-size: 16pt;
color: navy;
font-family: Arial;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding: 40px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lucro-esq {
width: 50%;
height: 100px;
font-size: 12pt;
color: navy;
font-family: Arial;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: flex-end;
flex-direction: column;
}

#reset {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
background-color: red;
border: none;
color: white;
font-size: 15pt;
float: left;
}

#calc {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
background-color: green;
border: none;
color: white;
font-size: 15pt;
float: left;
}

input {
width: 40px;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 10px;
font-size: 12pt;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bolder;
}

#pintar-opt {
display: none;
}
```

The JS (i'm also using jquery):

```
$('#pintar').click(function () {
$('#pintar-opt').slideToggle(0);
});



var p1, p2, p2_1, p2_2, p2_3, a;
p1 = 10; //penteado
p2 = 0; // pintar
p2_1 = 3; //opt cor 1
p2_2 = 5; //opt cor 2
p2_3 = 7; //opt cor 3
a = 6; //acabamento

var custo = [];

$('#penteado').click(function () {
custo.push(p1);
});

$('#pintar').click(function () {
custo.push(p2);
});

$('#cor_verm').click(function () {
custo.push(p2_1);
});

$('#cor_loiro').click(function () {
custo.push(p2_2);
});

$('#cor_cast').click(function () {
custo.push(p2_3);
});

$('#acabamento').click(function () {
custo.push(p2_3);
});

var preco = custo.join(" * ");
```

Very much appreciated to anyone who tries to help me! also, it would be awesome if you could see what's wrong with the design, as it is not properly responsive…

Comment: regarding the responsiveness of your css it would help if you could add a diagram image of the intended layout.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet performs the calculations. By cycling through the array elements using `$.each` and adding each one to a variable `num` (commented within the script) we can perform the addition. I've commented out the element joining line as I'm not sure why this is necessary.

n.b. The same outcome could be achieved without an array by simply incrementing and then multiplying the `num` variable, so it is assumed you'll be performing other tasks with the array elsewhere.

```js
$('#pintar').click(function() {
  $('#pintar-opt').slideToggle(0);
});


var p1 = 10, //penteado
  p2 = 0, // pintar
  p2_1 = 3, //opt cor 1
  p2_2 = 5, //opt cor 2
  p2_3 = 7, //opt cor 3
  a = 6; //acabamento

var custo = [];

function totals() {
  var num = 0, // define num 
    percen = parseFloat($('#perc').val()) || 0, // get the input number or enter 0 if no user input
    percen = percen * 0.01, //convert the percentage
    sum = 0; // the total
  $.each(custo, function() { // cycle through custo
    num += parseFloat(this); // increase num by element value
  });
  sum = (num * percen).toFixed(2); // calculate and round to two decimal places
  return sum; // return aumrray sum times percentage

}

$('#penteado').click(function() {
  custo.push(p1);
});

$('#pintar').click(function() {
  custo.push(p2);
});

$('#cor_verm').click(function() {
  custo.push(p2_1);
});

$('#cor_loiro').click(function() {
  custo.push(p2_2);
});

$('#cor_cast').click(function() {
  custo.push(p2_3);
});

$('#acabamento').click(function() {
  custo.push(p2_3);
});

$('#calc').click(function() {
  $('#resultado').text(totals()); // call on the totals() function
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  custo = []; // reset custo and num
  $('#resultado').text(0);
});

// var preco = custo.join(" * "); <- not sure why you're joining them here?
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inner-cont {
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #f2ce9e;
  position: relative;
}
#resultado {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: snow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px dashed #e39835;
}
.bloco-estilo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: navy;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
ul li:hover {
  background-color: #8b1555;
  color: white;
}
.bloco-estilo:hover {
  background-color: deeppink;
  color: white;
}
.lucro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: navy;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.lucro-dir {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: navy;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.lucro-esq {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: navy;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#reset {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15pt;
  float: left;
}
#calc {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15pt;
  float: left;
}
input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#pintar-opt {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-cont">
      <div id="resultado"></div>
      <div class="bloco-estilo" id="penteado">
        <p>Penteado</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bloco-estilo" id="pintar">
        <p>Pintar</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bloco-estilo" id="pintar-opt">
        <ul class="cores">
          <li id="cor_verm">Vermelho</li>
          <li id="cor_loiro">Loiro</li>
          <li id="cor_cast" cast>Castanho</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="bloco-estilo" id="acabamento">
        <p>Acabamento</p>
      </div>






      <div class="lucro">
        <div class="lucro-dir">
          <p>Introduza o valor percentual de lucro</p>
          <input id="perc" type="text" maxlength="2">
          <p>%</p>
        </div>

        <div class="lucro-esq">
          <button id="reset">Reset</button>
          <button id="calc">Calcular</button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me… gives me output of 0 in the display div, also, console says percen can not be found

Comment: adjusted the way the totals() function returns and rounded the result to two decimal places. should be working now.

Comment: now everytime i hit the calculate button i get 0.00

Comment: you require a user to enter a percentage and click on the buttons before performing a calculation. If there is no percentage entered then it assumes 0% (if you change the `percen = parseFloat($('#perc').val()) || 0` to `percen = parseFloat($('#perc').val()) || 100` then it will assume 100%) you can set other defaults by preloading the array

Comment: Alternatively you can set a default percentage in the html of the input tag with the attribute `...value=50 />`